# Move between tkinter frames

Tags: python-3.x, oop, tkinter

I have a main page that has 8 different frames in it. In every frame there is a back button which leads the frame to the main page. Also I have a converter frame which does some mathematical operations that are needed in all frames. In the converter frame there is also a back button but the back button leads the frame to the main page again. I want to go back from converter frame to the previous frame not to the main page.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk  

class Application(tk.Tk):

def __init__(self):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self)
    tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Geodesic Calculations")  

    container = tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.frames = {}

    for F in (StartPage, A_section, B_section, C_section, D_section,
              E_section, F_section, G_section, H_section, Converter):
        frame = F(container, self)
        self.frames[F] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    self.show_frame(StartPage)

def show_frame(self, cont):
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()
    return frame
```

Section A: (One of the 8 frames)

```
class A_section(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    btton = ttk.Button(self, text="Converter",
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Converter))
    btton.grid(row=0, column=5)

    button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    button1.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Converter Frame:

```
class Converter(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):                                     
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)                      


    button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back",
                     command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    button1.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

For example, when I'm in Section A, I want to use the converter, make calculations and then back to the Section A with the back button in converter frame. But the back button in the converter frame goes back to the home page, not to the section A. As shown in the code, in converter class there is a "Back" button which leads the frame to main page, how should i change the code's "controller.show_frame(StartPage)" part so in parantheses there should be the section name which i want to go back, not 'StartPage'.

Comment: Store your frames in a list and then you can load them based on index. Or you can use the show_frame method to lift the frame you need with a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the current displayed frame in `show_frame()` and show the saved frame when calling `show_frame()` with `cont` as `None`.  Below is the modified `show_frame()`:

```
def show_frame(self, cont=None):
  if cont is None:
    # show last frame
    cont = self.lastcont
  frame = self.frames[cont]
  frame.tkraise()
  if cont != Converter:
    self.lastcont = cont
```

Then modify the `command` option of `Back` button in `Converter` page:

```
button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back", command=lambda: controller.show_frame())
```